# Is 'pgd' Attribute Physical or Virtual Address in mm_struct in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmu

In Arm32 architecture(Flat Memory Model), 'pgd' attribute in mm_struct is a virtual address. If I understood correctly, however, in Arm64 architecture(Sparse Memory Model), 'pgd' attribute in mm_struct is a physical address.

Why there is such a difference between the two architecture? Why pgd in Arm64 isn't a virtual address?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you include your sources?

Comment: @wxz The source is the Linux kernel itself

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME I was asking for a link so I could quickly see it myself instead of having to do the research OP already did all over again, but ok...

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood.
The pgd is also stored as a virtual address in the sparse memory model.